# Connecting SQL Instance/Server without common Domain

Tags: sql, sql-server, dns

I am working on a group sourced project that requires a SQL database that we all need to connect to remotely. We don't have a common domain or VPN to connect to one so I read creating a SQL Server Authentication and TCP port could circumvent that.

I have setup the server and database directly on my laptop and followed the Microsoft documentation to create a TCP Fixed Port and created the corresponding rule in my firewall.

I then created the login and permissions for the SQL Server Authentication.

I tested the login on my laptop (where the server is hosted) and on my PC desktop (a totally different computer) and it worked just fine.

However, when my team members tried to access it from their remote locations I get the following error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

I assume this is because they don't share my IP/domain on my home internet as my desktop and laptop do.

Is there any way to connect to a SQL database remotely without being on the same domain?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Shouldn't I be able to connect without the domain using SQL Authentication? For some reason when i run the runas command in your answer I cannot type my passoword into the command line, keys just wont type

Comment: Also I cant have everyone run a command line anytime they want to connect so not really a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume this is because they don't share my IP/domain on my home internet as my desktop and laptop do.

Correct.  Your home network is behind a firewall and hosts on the internet are not allowed to connect.

For limited dev purposes you could use a tunneling solution like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

After you sign up and download, assuming your SQL Server is on port 1433, run

```
PS C:\utils> .\ngrok tcp 1433
```

which will inform you of the tunnel details:

> ngrok by @inconshreveable
> (Ctrl+C to quit)
> Session Status                online
> Account                       David Browne (Plan: Free)
> Version                       2.3.40
> Region                        United States (us)
> Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
> Forwarding                    tcp://4.tcp.ngrok.io:17247 ->
> localhost:1433
> Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50
> p90
> 0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

Which tells you to use `tcp:4.tcp.ngrok.io,17247` in your connection string.

Or you could move to a database hosted and accessable on the internet, like [Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/azure-sql/database/?OCID=AID2200277_SEM_6fe4e831c24014f5cc3f8a2f6eb45f95:G:s&ef_id=6fe4e831c24014f5cc3f8a2f6eb45f95:G:s&msclkid=6fe4e831c24014f5cc3f8a2f6eb45f95).

Comment: AZURE was the way, though Im learning its painful to use